# Implementing if-condition in preprocessor

Tags: javascript, preprocessor

For a project of mine, I want to implement a customized preprocessor in JavaScript that mimics the GNU C Preprocessor (i.e. `gcc -E`).

This preprocessor I wrote already has most things working, except conditionals. So, `#ifdef`, `#ifndef`, `#else` and `#endif` is what I am stuck at.

My code thus far: [preprocessor.js](https://github.com/DragonsInn/OhSoJuicy/blob/fcfd271fa30ce8e2f71cf3032f75000c342a4d62/lib/preprocessor.js) (permanent link)

I'd be glad to hear about suggestions on how to implement it! :)

Comment: does it guard against seeing string literals with keywords in it?

Comment: What exactly are you stuck at? What have you tried, what did not work? Can you please post the relevant code in your question?

Comment: @dandavis Defined value are written into the source as-is. It works like the C preprocessor in that regard - that is, if I have not missed something.

Comment: @Bergi I posted the entire code. I am stuck at the idea of how to implement the if-logic entirely. What is the best way to translate the if condition into a javascript expression and then handling nested if's, or multiple levels of them to be exact. I just kinda seem to be hitting a roadblock here...its why im asking here.

Comment: @IngwiePhoenix: You didn't post any code, you posted a link to github.

Comment: @Bergi Should I copypaste the whole code into my question? O.o wouldn't that be rather unpractical? That is why I used a permanent link to the file - since it is already posted online. That is my very code so... But if you want me to still copypaste it into the question, I can do that.

Comment: No, please post only the relevant parts of it. We don't care how you're loading your file for example, but we care what kind of algorithm you use. The full code being linked is nice, but your question [should include everything necessary to answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428) - just like a [link to the full corrected code wouldn't be an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maintain a stack of conditions and keep skipping lines as long as any condition is false. In pseudocode:

```
 for each line
    if line == "#if <cond>"
        conditions.push(<cond>)
    else if line == "#else" 
        conditions.push(!conditions.pop())
    else if line == "#endif" 
        conditions.pop()
    else if all conditions are true
        everything fine, handle line
    else
        skip line
```

Comment: Oh! So you mean like, a stack of conditions? Hmm... That is quite interesting. I will try this out and when it works mark the answer. Thanks for that, ill comment again when i got it working.

Comment: Implemented, tested, working. :) thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Better approach would be parsing into the AST which will contain clearly defined base blocks and control flow graphs.

For example "if" (conditional) construct can be expressed as

```
conditional
|
-- test
-- consequent base block
-- [alternate bb]
-- [elseif 1]
    |
    -- test
    -- consequent
   ...
```

This approach is much more flexible and allows creating full-scale language with functions, loops, contexts, etc.

Good example can be seen in *Builder* preprocessor: https://github.com/electricimp/Builder